# Retrofit, top level json object changes?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to make a few api calls. For a particular endpoint, the returned json looks a bit like this:

Endpoint: `api.example.com/1.0/userinfo?userid=7`

The returned response looks a bit like this:

```
{
    "7":{
        "name":"george",
        "age"="32"
        }

}
```

Basically, the top level object is whatever number gets passed into the url parameter (in this example 7).

So when creating my Java objects to model this response, how do I model this top level object so that even if the name changes it maps properly when using gson?

Answer (score 1):

Interface:

```
@Get
Call<Map<String,User>> getUserInfo(@Url String url);
```

Usages:

```
Map<String,User> response =getUserInfo("http://api.example.com/1.0/userinfo?userid=7");
User user = response.get("7");
```

"7" is userid=?

Interface:

```
@Get("1.0/userinfo")
Call<Map<String,User>> getUserInfo(@Query("userid")String userid);
```

Usages:

```
String userId = "7";
Map<String,User> response = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://api.example.com").create(ApiService.class).getUserInfo(userId).execute();
User user = response.get(userId);`
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why do you use a `Map`? I've used Retrofit a dozen times before but usually the json is structured so that the top level object key would be the same. So eg: the top level object would be something like `"userinfo":{"id": 88}` and I would create a model class for userinfo with an id variable. But since in this case the top level object changes, how do I model that?